Expected Prediction Error from The Elements of Statistical Learning
I am working self-studying the Elements of Statistical Learning and have a question regarding how equation $(2.28)$ is derived. Similar question here but without a satisfactory answer: How to formalize Elements of Statistical Learning's computation for the EPE of linear regression
Starting with equation $(2.27)$
$$
EPE(x_0) = \sigma^2 + \mathbb{E}_{\tau}x_0^T\big(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\big)^{-1}x_0\sigma^2 
$$
The author states that If $N$ is large and $\tau$ were selected at random, and assuming
$\mathbb{E}(X) = 0$, then $X^TX \rightarrow NCov(X)$ then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{x_0} EPE(x_0) & \sim \mathbb{E}_{x_0}x_0^T Cov(X)^{-1}x_0\sigma^2/N + \sigma^2\\
& = \text{trace}[Cov(X)^{-1}Cov(x_0)]\sigma^2/N + \sigma^2\\
& = \sigma^2(p/N) + \sigma^2
\end{align}
$p$ is the dimension of the data, $N$ is the sample size, $x_0$ is a test point and $\tau$ is the training data
The notes make this leap
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\tau}x_0^T\big(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\big)^{-1}x_0\sigma^2 & = \sigma^2x_0^T \mathbb{E}_{X_T}\big(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}/N\big)^{-1}x_0/N
\end{align}
$\mathbb{E}_{X_T}$ denotes the expectation over the training inputs and comes about through the factorisation of $\mathbb{E}_{\tau} = \mathbb{E}_{X_T} \mathbb{E}_{Y_T | X_T}$
So I have a few questions:

Where does $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}/N$ come from? Specifically the division by $N$?
Why for large $N$, does $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}/N$ approximately equal $COV(X) = COV(x_0)$?
Why do we take expectations over $x_0$ which is the sample text point? This has been treated as not random variable
Where does the trace element come from?

This is from chapter 2, page 26, equation (2.28) from the ESL book. I am using the excellent notes that accompany this here
I have been making my own notes with more detailed derivations and alongside some explanations from ChatGPT have been OK.

ChatGPT generally does not "know" anything or "think" in any meaningful way. At best, it synthesizes text to look human-written & predicts what the desired words should be; it does not do real calculations (more). It should not be used for math, as it will get basics wrong or "hallucinate" fake facts. Some extra examples: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.
